# Getting the display name for a subscribedSku from Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to get a list of subscribedSkus from our Office 365 tenant and their associated display names. I am calling the /beta/subscribedSkus endpoint but the only name it name I see is skuPartNumber which isn't very readable. Is there another endpoint I can call to get a display name?

Example: 
skuPartNumber: DYN365_ENTERPRISE_PLAN1
The license name in Office 365 Portal: Dynamics 365 Customer Engagement Plan Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There isn't an API for returning the descriptive service plan name.

Most (as best I can tell it is "all" but I'm hedging here just in case I'm mistaken) are documented at [Product names and service plan identifiers for licensing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-licensing-product-and-service-plan-reference). For example:

> **Product Name:** DYNAMICS 365 CUSTOMER ENGAGEMENT PLAN ENTERPRISE EDITION
>
> **String ID:** DYN365_ENTERPRISE_PLAN1
>
> **GUID:** ea126fc5-a19e-42e2-a731-da9d437bffcf
>
> **Service Plans Included:**
>
> - DYN365_ENTERPRISE_P1 (d56f3deb-50d8-465a-bedb-f079817ccac1)
> - FLOW_DYN_P2 (b650d915-9886-424b-a08d-633cede56f57)
> - NBENTERPRISE (03acaee3-9492-4f40-aed4-bcb6b32981b6)
> - POWERAPPS_DYN_P2 (0b03f40b-c404-40c3-8651-2aceb74365fa)
> - PROJECT_CLIENT_SUBSCRIPTION (fafd7243-e5c1-4a3a-9e40-495efcb1d3c3)
> - SHAREPOINT_PROJECT (fe71d6c3-a2ea-4499-9778-da042bf08063)
> - SHAREPOINTENTERPRISE (5dbe027f-2339-4123-9542-606e4d348a72)
> - SHAREPOINTWAC (e95bec33-7c88-4a70-8e19-b10bd9d0c014)